# Impedance matching (RF transformer) - Impedance dependence

Tags: rf, transformer

I'm using a TC2-1TG2 1 to 2 impedance trasnformer. I want to convert a 50 ohm load to 25 but I'm finding that the transformer only works for 50 to 100 as seen in the following simulation:

[image]

Is there something that can be done about this?

Thank you,

Joao

Comment: Operate it as a step down converter and not a step up converter.

Answer (score 0):

> *I'm using a TC2-1TG2 1 to 2 impedance trasnformer. I want to convert a
> 50 ohm load to 25 but I'm finding that the transformer only works for
> 50 to 100*

If you want to impedance match a 50 ohm source to a 25 ohm load then you need to step down the voltage and not step it up. Try operating the transformer in reverse to how you connected it in your tests i.e. primary = higher number of turns and secondary = lower number of turns.

Your turns ratio for 2:1 impedance transforming should be \$\sqrt2\$:1.

Alternatively, if your bandwidth is limited, use an L-Pad impedance transformer.

Comment: Thats what I did for the 50 to 25 ohm.

Comment: @Joao I don't follow. In your question you said you tested it 50 to 100 and also showed results of 25 to 50. If there's something I'm missing then you really do need to be clearer because I haven't got my mind-reading head on this morning.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I didn't explain myself clearly. My problem is with the difference in performance of the transformer at those two different loads (25 to 50 vs 50 to 100)

Comment: You must still believe that I'm a mind reader @Joao. I have no idea what the problem appears to be. The graphs don't tell me what you consider to be bad for your particular situation. The graphs look neither good nor bad to me because I can't read your mind and see what the problem is.